How to save API keys securely?
I have seen people recommend use dotenv package to manage API keys in Flutter, I used it before but I seen this. When you create an apk file and use any online decompilators for apk, .env files are there, manifest and more. So what’s the right way to manage API keys? I'm staring to think that dotenv does not make sense if is so easy to see the files. Also I added some restrictions for APIs from Google console but the keys are still outside.

If you want to store information on your App Runtime such as Access/Refresh tokens or any other sensible information you should use libs able to encrypt the stored data. I always use the flutter_secure_storage. This package will use the secure native methods to store the information encrypted.
But reading your context's question, I understood that your doubt is about how to protect and obfuscate your builds in order to protect your .env file. To solve this you can use an built-in feature on flutter cli. You can read more in this article.
But beyond these solutions you can think in many methods to solve this. Like renew your tokens periodically using your a Web API that you own, or encrypt your data an use a Web API to decrypt it only to your app requests, and other ways.

You may use some algorithm provided by library using encryption.

this won't solve the issue described. He wants to know about obfuscation/strategies to hide his .env file informations

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
